# Files are being downloaded at pythonanywhere server and user laptop/pc too. How to restrict to write at pythonanywhere server

Tags: django, video, download, pythonanywhere

Problem is i have hosted at pythonanywhere using django.Video is downloaded at pythonanywhere server and user/client system too.Thats why i used os. remove(path).After downloading it removes from server.

Is there any ways files donot write on pyhtonanywhere server. so that i donot use os.remove(path).
How to restrict to write at pythonanywhere server. Only to download at user system.

def fb_download(request):

```
link = request.GET.get('url')
html= requests.get(link)
try:       
    url= re.search('hd_src:"(.+?)"',html.text)[1]
except:
    url= re.search('sd_src:"(.+?)"',html.text)[1]



path=wget.download(url, 'Video.mp4')
response=FileResponse(open(path, 'rb'), as_attachment=True)
os.remove(path)
return response
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to get a request from a browser, which contains a URL.  You then access the page at that URL and extract a further URL from it, and then you want to present the contents of that second URL -- a video -- to the browser.

The way you are doing that is to download the file to the server, and then to serve that up as a file attachment to the browser.

If you do it that way, then there is no way to avoid writing the file on the server; indeed, the way you are doing it right now might have problems because you are deleting the file before you've returned the response to the browser, so there may (depending on how the file deletion is processed and whether the `FileResponse` caches the file's contents) be cases where there is no file to send back to the browser.

But an alternative way to do it that might work would be to send a redirect response to the URL -- the one in your variable `url` -- like this, without downloading it at all:

```
def fb_download(request):

    link = request.GET.get('url')
    html= requests.get(link)
    try:       
        url= re.search('hd_src:"(.+?)"',html.text)[1]
    except:
        url= re.search('sd_src:"(.+?)"',html.text)[1]
    
    return redirect(url)
```

By doing that, the download happens on the browser instead of on the server.

Comment: Thanks Giles for your response.This does not automate downloading in the absence of FileResponse.I am asking a trick whether it should automate downloading or browser should ask download location.

Comment: same issue over here ..please suggest this is biggest trouble for me.  path=YouTube(url).streams.filter(res=res).first().download(DOWNLOAD_DIR)

        response=FileResponse(open(path, 'rb'), as_attachment=True)

        os.remove(path)
        return response

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "automating downloading in the absence of FileResponse"

Comment: @GilesThomas The above solution didn't work. The re.search() returning None.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t understand javascript really good,
But i think if you download the file to the server
And then you can download the file to the use using JS
And i think you can use

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).